# PHP4 and static methods / callback functions

Tags: php, oop, static, php4

The `static` keyword was introduced in PHP5, which kinda makes one come to the conclusion that PHP4 didn't support static methods or variables. And yet when I run the following code on PHP 4.4.9 it works without the constructor ever being called.

```
<?php
class a {
    function a() {
        echo "CONSTRUCTOR CALLED\r\n";
    }

    function b($var) {
        return $var . 'x';
    }
}

print_r(array_map(array('a', 'b'), array('a', 'b')));
```

You can play around with the code with this PHP "fiddle":

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d6882a8264620a0165d7345791f8680586a869e

Any ideas as to how this is working?

Comment: What has any of this code got to do with static functions? It's just a simple class callback

Comment: @MarkBaker It's an odd example, but `array('a', 'b')` as a callback represents `a::b`, i.e. a static function call.

Comment: It's calling the class method, but PHP4 OOP worked without the need for a static keyword as methods could be called statically or dynamically anyway, and as b() contains no instance references, there would be no error... it's only later versions that tightened up the rules

Comment: @MarkBaker Right, which is the answer to the OP's question. It's still a static call, and working in PHP 4 as such, even if PHP 4 didn't have a keyword for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the `static` keyword does is tell PHP that a function *should* be called statically. In actual fact, even the latest versions will let you call any function statically if you want, as [this online demo with your code in multiple PHP versions](http://3v4l.org/ochLd) shows.

If you [turn error reporting to the max, as in this demo](http://3v4l.org/tjOhK) you will see that newer versions of PHP give an `E_STRICT` message that you're using a function statically that hasn't been declared as such, but otherwise run the code exactly as before.

All that's needed to make a static function call is `::`, and that was present and correct in PHP 4. It's really the *non-static* methods that were tidied up in PHP 5, and further in 5.3